# print array values testCafe typeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

Please help me to figure out how to get actual values from array instead of these:

```
[object ReExecutablePromise]
[object ReExecutablePromise]
[object ReExecutablePromise]
[object ReExecutablePromise]
[object ReExecutablePromise]
```

here is my code example:

```
test('Reference Type', async t=>{
  await loginPage.login(oceanconfig.testUser, oceanconfig.password);
  await t.click(HomePage.button);
  const rowsNum = await CreateShipmentPage.referenceTypeOption().count;
  const arr = [];

  for(let i = 1; i< rowsNum-1; i++){
    const  referenceType = CreateShipmentPage.referenceTypeSelect().innerText;
    arr.push(referenceType);
  }
  const item = await arr.slice(1, 6);
  for (let row of item) {
    console.log(row);
  }  
 })
```

Comment: They appear to be a variant of promises. In which case, you can `await` them (or use their `.then` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you miss the 'await' operator when getting 'referenceType'.
Please try the code below:

```
test('Reference Type', async t=>{
  await loginPage.login(oceanconfig.testUser, oceanconfig.password);
  await t.click(HomePage.button);
  const rowsNum = await CreateShipmentPage.referenceTypeOption().count;
  const arr = [];

  for(let i = 1; i< rowsNum-1; i++){
    const  referenceType = await CreateShipmentPage.referenceTypeSelect().innerText;
    arr.push(referenceType);
  }
  const item = await arr.slice(1, 6);
  for (let row of item) {
    console.log(row);
  }  
 })
```